# Solve $\arctan(ax)+\arctan(bx)+\arctan(cx) = \pi$ as $x=\frac{\sqrt{a+b+c}}{\sqrt{abc}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, angle

I know that is made applying the cosine and with a inverse trigonometric relationship, but I'm stuck after that.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\tan\{\arctan(ax)+\arctan(bx)+\arctan(cx)\}=\dfrac{(a+b+c)x-abcx^3}{1-x^2(ab+bc+ca)}$$

For $x=\dfrac{\sqrt{a+b+c}}{\sqrt{abc}},$

$$(a+b+c)x-abcx^3=(a+b+c)\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{a+b+c}}{\sqrt{abc}}-abc\cdot\dfrac{(a+b+c)^{3/2}}{(abc)^{3/2}}=0$$

$\implies \arctan(ax)+\arctan(bx)+\arctan(cx)=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

As $\arctan(y)<\dfrac\pi2$ for real finite $y$  we need $ax,bx,cx>0$

otherwise $\arctan(ax)+\arctan(bx)+\arctan(cx)<\pi$

If $a,b,c>0;$ we need $x>0$

As $abc>0,$ even number of  terms in $\in\{a,b,c\}$ must be negative.

But we need $a,b,c$ of same sign as $x\implies a,b,c$ must be $>0$

Answer (score 1):

let $\tan \alpha = ax$, $\tan \beta = bx$, $\tan \theta = cx$.

$$
\tan (\alpha + \beta) = \frac{\tan \alpha + \tan \beta}{1 - \tan \alpha \tan \beta}
= \frac{a x + b x}{1 - ab x^2}
$$

Substituting in $x= \frac{\sqrt{a+b+c}}{\sqrt{abc}}$ and working through leads to

$$
\tan (\alpha + \beta) = \frac{- c \sqrt{a+b+c} }{\sqrt{abc}} = - c x = -\tan{\theta}
$$

which provides the result that $\alpha + \beta + \theta = \pi$ if we assume that $a,b,c$ (and hence $x$) are positive and finite, i.e. that $0 < \alpha, \beta, \theta < \pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> I'll assume $\ds{a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}_{\ >\ 0}}$

\begin{align}
x & = {\root{a + b + c} \over \root{abc}} \implies abcx^{2} = a + b + c \implies
abcx^{3} - cx = ax + bx
\\[5mm]
\implies cx &= {ax + b x \over abx^{2} - 1} =
{1/\pars{bx} + 1/\pars{ax} \over 1 - \bracks{1/\pars{bx}}\bracks{1/\pars{ax}}}
\\[5mm] \implies
\arctan\pars{cx} & = \arctan\pars{1 \over bx} + \arctan\pars{1 \over ax}
\\[5mm] \implies
\arctan\pars{cx} & = \bracks{{\pi \over 2} - \arctan\pars{bx}} +
\bracks{{\pi \over 2} - \arctan\pars{ax}}
\\[5mm] \implies
&\bbx{\ds{\arctan\pars{ax} + \arctan\pars{bx} + \arctan\pars{cx} = \pi}}
\end{align}